# PageRequestManagerServerErrorException error when I press F5 while updatepanel is updating

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, error-handling, updatepanel

I have a updatepanel that is updated using timer every one second.
I also have async postback error handler set up in javascript as following:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(onEndRequest);

function onEndRequest(sender, args) {
var error = args.get_error();
if (error != null) {
    args.set_errorHandled(true);
    alert(error.message);
}
```

}

when I refresh the page manually or click a hyperlink I get the following error in endRequest handler:

> An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server.
>   The status code returned from the server was: 0

How can i prevent this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: You get this error on alert() ? on client side ? I think is normal if he wait for a replay and you break it.

Comment: Then how do I cancel async request from JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

For thoue who have the same problem, here is the code to determine if script manager async postback is currently running:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()
```

to cancel it call:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().abortPostBack();
```

I just call the cancel method directly. It does not not anything when request is not running.